# Problem with SQL on databricks, works on SQL Server but fails on databricks

Tags: sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to run the below query on databricks and got this.

DataType datetime is not supported.(line 2, pos 84)

```
SELECT
EOMONTH (
     CAST(
        FORMAT(DATEADD(month, - 14, GETDATE()), 
     'yyyy-MM-01 00:00:00.000') AS datetime)) AS eom, 
CAST(
     FORMAT(
        DATEADD(month, - 14, GETDATE()), 
     'yyyy-MM-01 00:00:00.000') AS datetime) AS start_tm2
```

below is the format is was looking for

eom               start_tm2
2021-11-30  2021-11-01 00:00:00.000

We are on Databricks 9.1 and date_add function is not working.

Comment: Why are you formatting a datetime? It's usually a bad idea. If you explain further perhaps we can assist, but most likely you shouldn't be formatting it. None of the functions above are supported in spark SQL  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by **@Nick.McDermaid**, all the above functions are not supported in spark SQL, and SQL and spark SQL are somewhat different. Thats why it gave you the error.

I have reproduced the above in same environment and able to achieve your requirement using spark SQL functions like below. But not sure about the performance as it depends on your data.

```
%sql
SELECT last_day(date_format(add_months(current_date(),-14), 'yyyy-MM-01 00:00:00.000')) as EOM,date_format(add_months(current_date(),-14), 'yyyy-MM-01 00:00:00.000') as start_tm2;
```

**Execution:**

[image]